# Python : How to save object state and reuse it

Tags: serialization, python

I want to save object state and reuse it after some time. 
I got some example on How to save object (Pickle module), I was not able to find how to resume class/method from the save state and proceed further.

Like game, we can save the game and latter we can continue, I know in game we save all the data and game read the data and build the game.

I want to save complete object and when I restore it it start working from saved state.

For example

```
class Test(objet):
   def doSomeWork(self):
     index = 0
     while index < 99999:
        print index 
        index  += 1
        if saveCondition:
          # suppose when condition become True index value is 100
          saveCondition = None
          saveTheObjectToFile() # this might be saved in file
restoreClassObject = getSavedObject() # get object from file
# Now this should start printing from 100
# I want to resume the object state when it was saved.
```

Comment: I don't think I understand you question. Who is `i` in the code you posted ? Why don't you serialize the current index (by making it an attribute) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to make sure that the state of the Object is not saved in local scopes, but as attributes of the object. Consider

```
import cPickle

class Test(objet):
    def __init__(self, filename="mystate.pickle"):
        self.index = 0
        self.filename = filename

    def save(self):
        f = open(self.filename, 'w')
        cPickle.dump(self, f)
        f.close

    def doSomeWork(self):
        while self.index < 99999:
            print self.index 
            self.index  += 1
            if self.saveCondition:
              # suppose when condition become True index value is 100
              self.saveCondition = False
              self.save() # this might be saved in file

restoreClassObject = getSavedObject() # get object from file
```

Of course `doSomeWork` makes no sense as such, but for the sake of the example imagine this method was a Thread so you could still interact with the object by setting it's `restoreClassObject.saveCondition = True` to save it in the next iteration step.

Answer (score 0):

CPython doesn't have the kind of [continuations that stackless](http://www.stackless.com/spcpaper.htm#_Toc470444056) has so you might not be able to serialise the entire program state and store it in a file.

You'll have to write some kind of layer than serialises your application data and puts it in a file to implement saving.