# Python restoring an interrupt iteration of two lists

Tags: python, iteration, pickle

Here the code:

```
import itertools
# import list from file
a = [line.strip() for line in open("real.txt", 'r')]
b = [line.strip() for line in open("imag.txt", 'r')]

# create file contain restore informations 
f = open("restore.txt","w+")
loop = 0
try:
    for r in itertools.product(a,b):
         loop +=1
         print "processing : "+ r[1] + ": "+ r[0] + "  ("+str(loop)+")"

except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
    f.write("iterazions seccession: " +str(loop)+"\n")
    f.write("real number : " +r[1]+"\n")
    f.write("imaginary unit: " + r[0]+ "\n")
```

**example output**

```
processing: 1 : 1i (1)
processing: 1 : 2i (2)
processing: 1 : 3i (3)
processing: 1 : 4i (4)
...
processing: 2000 : 174i (348000)
processing: 2000 : 175i (348001)
...and so forth
(it does all combinations of two lists)
```

the question is if an error stop the iteration, there's a way to restart the script from last iteration without start from scratch?
I try saving the last value in a file but I do not know how to use it.

*p.s. I know the cmath function for complex number but  I’m more interested to restore issue*

**more specific**

if an error stop the iteration at:
processing: 2000 : 175i (348001)
there is a way to restart the script from *2000 : 175i (348001)* iteration?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is. Please give an example where an error would stop.

Comment: any error that might stop the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **My solution**

so, my question was *"how restart the script from last iteration without start from scratch?"*.
First I try in the [hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864809/using-itertools-product-and-want-to-seed-a-value/9865149#9865149) and even if it works fine I realize a way much more simple than that (kiss right?). Here the code:

```
import itertools
import pickle  #for restoring last data session
fname = "restore.pck"

reals = [line.strip() for line in open("real.txt", 'r')]
imags = [line.strip() for line in open("imag.txt", 'r')]

seed_count = 0 #number last processing cycle
count_ses = 0  #number current session cycle
count_tot = 0  #number total cycle processing so far
it_tot=len(reals)*len(imgs)

ret = raw_input("recover last session?: y/n")
if ret =="y":
    with open(fname,"rb") as f:
        rec= pickle.load(f)
        print  "last session data {0} {1} {2}".format(rec[0],rec[1],rec[2])
        seed_count=rec[2]
        seed_img=rec[1]
        seed_rea=rec[0]
try:
 print "total iterations", it_tot

 for r in itertools.product(reals,imgs):
    # do nothing until you get last interrupted cycle
    count_tot+=1
    if count_tot >= seed_count:
    # and now start processing
     count_ses +=1
     print "processing: {0}, {1}, (total : {2}), (this session: {3}) {4}% )".format(r[0], r[1], count_tot, count_ses,(count_tot/len_tot*100))

except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
    #save data if an error occurred
    store = r[0], r[1], count_tot
    with open(fname,"wb") as f:
     pickle.dump(store,f,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
     f.close()
```

It simply let run the iteration without processing anything until It reaches the last processing cycle and then restart computing.
Of course some "wiseguy" will say *this is not the pythonic way* or *this code it's a mess, is not fancy like mine* but this is my first python program, it works and I'm happy:)

Answer (score 3):

Put the try/except INSIDE the for loop - if the except doesn't raise then the for loop will continue.

```
for r in itertools.product(a,b):
    try:
         loop +=1
         print "processing : "+ r[1] + ": "+ r[0] + "  ("+str(loop)+")"
             #enable for testing error
             #if loop == 15:
                 #loop = loop/0
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
        f.write("iterazions seccession: " +str(loop)+"\n")
        f.write("real number : " +r[1]+"\n")
        f.write("imaginary unit: " + r[0]+ "\n")
```

Comment: thanks. but is possible restore an interrupted session without start from scratch?

Comment: Automagically, no. If you write code that saves the current state and (optionally) uses a saved current state when restarting, then yes, in general, although I don't know if it is possible to resume itertools.product - basically you will have to implement whatever is needed to do the resume.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'll see the use of `try ... except` blocks, which are relatively inexpensive in Python.

This won't stop execution of your loop, as seen in this example (which can be applied to your situation):

```
numbers = [1, 3, 2, 5, 0, 4, 5]

for number in numbers:
  try:
    print(10/number)
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Please don't divide by 0...")
```

You'll see the output to this in Python 2.7.11 is:

```
10
3
5
2
Please don't divide by 0...
2
2
```

If your code can throw multiple types of exceptions, you can chain them:

```
numbers = [1, 3, 2, 5, 0, 4, 5]

for number in numbers:
  try:
    print(10/number)
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Please don't divide by 0...")
  except ValueError:
    print("Something something ValueError")
  except KeyError:
    print("Something something KeyError")
```

If you know all the types of exceptions your code can raise, you can handle them appropriately, which is typically a better solution than a general solution for exceptions.

---

General notes about your code:

## Use more representative names for variables

- Using more representative names will help the user/maintainer understand what's going on with your code **and** help you catch bugs. `a` and `b` don't mean much in terms of real and imaginary numbers - why not use `real_nums` and `imag_nums`? Not much more typing and much more descriptive.

## Use `open(file) as f`

- This will close your file automatically so you don't need to worry about it later, which can be problematic for writing/appending

## Use `enumerate(iterable)`

- this will keep track of iteration number and the object at the iteration

## Iterate over tuples

- You won't need to access with `[]` notation - you can just use the elements within the tuples directly.

## Use format strings

- These will make your code look a little nicer when printing

Putting all this together:

```
import itertools
# import list from file

reals = [line.strip() for line in open("real.txt", 'r')]
imags = [line.strip() for line in open("imag.txt", 'r')]

# create file contain restore informations 
with open("restore.txt", "w+") as f:
    for i, (real, imag) in enumerate(itertools.product(reals, imags)):
        try:
            print "processing: {0}, {1}, ({2})".format(real, imag, i) 
            # Process data here

            #enable for testing error
            if i == 15:
                i = i/0
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            # Handle exception here
            continue
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e)
            f.write("iterazions seccession: {0}\n".format(i))
            f.write("real number: {0}\n".format(real))
            f.write("imaginary unit: {0}\n".format(imag))
```

Comment: Typically you'll want to know what types of exceptions to expect - otherwise it makes the coder look careless. You can remove `ZeroDivisionError` and it will still work, but you'll gain no information about what caused the exception.

Comment: ok. but if an error stop the code there is a way to restart it at the last point processing?

Comment: I guess I still don't understand what you're asking... This doesn't stop your processing.

Comment: sorry... try to explain it another way. if I want to pause the script and restart? it's possible?

Comment: Why would you want to pause your script? The idea is to write code that can handle exceptions, not something that requires the user to handle it.

Comment: the data file are stored in a server, when the connection fall down i have to start over.

Comment: That's a much better question.

Comment: Sounds like we're getting to the X of the XY problem.

Comment: @marioLetterman This might be a good option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876159/pause-before-retry-connection-in-python However, if there's no need to separate this code from the server, I wouldn't. For example, do your processing on the server and send the results to the client.

Comment: maybe a better option:[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673127/python-how-to-save-object-state-and-reuse-it) and : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299349/how-to-stop-and-resume-long-time-running-python-script/6299672#6299672) it's closer to what I looking for

Comment: I don't think you really want to serialize your code. Good luck, though.